# Multiple Regression - How to find the case that worsens my model the most?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

**The big picture problem**

I am missing participants for a Multiple Regression (MR) (as judged by a-priori power analysis). I want to be able to say: "Not enough participants, but even in the **worst-case scenario**, our model remains significant".

**The specific problem**

The problem is defining "**worst-case scenario**". The way I think about it is this: Take the case in the data that **worsens the model the most**; then multiply that case until I get to the desired N and re-run MR.

**The more specific problem**

Okay, but how do I find the case that worsens the model the most?

My initial thought was to calculate Mahalanobis and Cook's distances and use the highest values as a guide. Then, I removed each case and looked at R-R^2-p change: the case that, when removed, improves the fit of the model (or in other words, when added worsens the model) by most is my worst case.

**What I have tried**

I have already tried the above: My initial model had `R^2 = 0.198, p=0.008` (n=66, 4 predictors throughout). I added the worst case 9 times (to get to 77 which is one of our thresholds) and that worsened the model to `R^2 = 0.138, p=0.032`. Then I added it another 8 times (to get to 85, which is our ultimate threshold) and that gave me a model 'in the middle' - `R^2 = 0.145, p=0.015`

I have also looked for ways to plot differences in overall model fit but failed miserably. Best I found is to plot estimates for individual predictors:
[Comparison of estimates of individual predictors for two models - Model 1 is the initial model and Model 2 has the biggest potential outlier removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQxoN.png)

I am not posting my data as I am not particularly interested in the specific, but rather what would be the general approach to answering the big picture problem as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on what purpose you done the regression analysis. This is how i would tackle this problem.

I wouldn't add rows to the data but instead;

If it is for prediction i would go for RMSE, or CV score (now i see that n is a problem so i would go for the former) with only significant predictor variables.

If its for explanatory purpose i would go for adjusted R-square with only significant explanatory variables.

But explain to the audience that n is low and this should only be used for a broad understanding. Make sure that if they want a more precise result, you need more funding for data collection.

Edit: And keep a close look for big drops in n when adding a variable.

Comment: Hi Christian! Great initial directions! I actually think my initial question is slightly ill-advised. Adding new rows to the data in MR seems like a bad idea because regardless of which case I add - even if it's an outlier - it will generally improve the fit of the model (in my data it improves relative model fit, e.g. R^2, while absolute model fit, e.g. RMSE as you suggested, is on a curve depending on how many times I add the identified outlier). Given the lack of N, I am also focusing on R^2 only, not on individual predictors. Given my high effect size, hopefully this will suffice. Cheers!